# Longitudinal waves - Speed of sound vs Salinity

Tags: waves, acoustics, water

I [have read](https://sciencing.com/water-affect-sound-8510076.html) that speed of sound in water increases with salinity "Sound travels faster in the ocean because there are more molecules — specifically salt molecules — for waves to interact with, as well as higher surface temperatures." However, this confuses me as
$$v=\sqrt{K/\rho}.$$
Thus it makes sense to me that velocity is inversely proportional to density (the opposite of what the article says). However, I could be wrong.

Regardless I have seen some data and it is true that a higher salinity (thus higher density) is increasing speed of sound in water. How does this work, as surely a higher density would decrease sound speed?

Comment: It is worth noting that while the velocity is also proportional to $\sqrt{K}$, where $K$ is the bulk modulus.  If $v$ is getting larger while $\rho$ is getting larger, this equation seems to say that $K$ is getting larger faster.  It might be worth looking into what salinity does to the bulk modulus of the water.